# How to solve: Error: value of pendingCustomerTokenList must be a collection in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, apache-axis

Have an app that I am creating in flashbuilder 4, java axis 2 web service and mysql.

In my app I have defined a service.  I have not had problems with pulling data and inserting data by calling my java functions through the service.

I added a new property and then made it available in flex.  It displayed on my label field, but then I ran the app and got the following error:

```
Error: value of pendingCustomerTokenList must be a collection
at valueObjects::_Super_PendingTokensResponse/set pendingCustomerTokenList()[F:\vEngage\flexworkspace\FBAgentApp\src\valueObjects\_Super_PendingTokensResponse.as:104]
at com.adobe.serializers.utility::TypeUtility$/assignProperty()[/Users/sameer/depot/flex/ide_builder/com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad/serializers/src/com/adobe/serializers/utility/TypeUtility.as:559] 
at com.adobe.serializers.utility::TypeUtility$/convertToStrongType()[/Users/sameer/depot/flex/ide_builder/com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad/serializers/src/com/adobe/serializers/utility/TypeUtility.as:498]
at com.adobe.serializers.utility::TypeUtility$/convertResultHandler()[/Users/sameer/depot/flex/ide_builder/com.adobe.flexbuilder.dcrad/serializers/src/com/adobe/serializers/utility/TypeUtility.as:372]
```

I looked at the Network Monitor tab and examined the call/response.  Response body shows no error, and the Response result shows the data returned by my java axis 2 function.  It is all correct.

Ran configure return type again.  Let it auto-detect and return type from sample data. The properties returned looked just fine.

Looked at the _Super_PendingTokensResponse.as on line 104

How do I correct this problem?

Comment: Could you post the code for `_Super_PendingTokensResponse.as`?  Also, what is the web service sending for the value of `pendingCustomerTokenList`?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your consuming webservice part.

Comment: Not an answer, you could have posted this as a comment!

Comment: Hi patel , do you have any idea on this issue? Please let me know.